# SVG: draw text with solid background color

Tags: svg

I would like to draw text in SVG with a solid background color, but I don't have access to the text size. (It's in a style element that's already been written into the document.) It would be easy with a rectangle, except that I would need to specify its size as "whatever the current text size is". Can I do that? Any other ideas?