# How to calculate length of string in pixels for specific font and size?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, fonts

If the font, e.g. "Times New Roman", and size, e.g. 12 pt, is known, how can the length of a string, e.g. "Hello world" be calculated in pixels, maybe only approximately?

I need this to do some manual right alignment of text shown in an Windows application, so I need to adjust the number spaces to get the alignment.

Comment: See https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.0/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getsize

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An alternative is to ask Windows as follows:

```
import ctypes

def GetTextDimensions(text, points, font):
    class SIZE(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [("cx", ctypes.c_long), ("cy", ctypes.c_long)]

    hdc = ctypes.windll.user32.GetDC(0)
    hfont = ctypes.windll.gdi32.CreateFontA(points, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, font)
    hfont_old = ctypes.windll.gdi32.SelectObject(hdc, hfont)

    size = SIZE(0, 0)
    ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetTextExtentPoint32A(hdc, text, len(text), ctypes.byref(size))

    ctypes.windll.gdi32.SelectObject(hdc, hfont_old)
    ctypes.windll.gdi32.DeleteObject(hfont)

    return (size.cx, size.cy)

print(GetTextDimensions("Hello world", 12, "Times New Roman"))
print(GetTextDimensions("Hello world", 12, "Arial"))
```

This would display:

```
(47, 12)
(45, 12)
```

Comment: Thanks; had to add `()` for print to use on Python 3, but otherwise it worked.  But odd that there is the significant x-size difference between the two methods.

Comment: There are quite a few dimensions you can take from a given font, so I am guessing `getsize()` is using a different one.

Comment: I'm getting AttributeError: module 'ctypes' has no attribute 'windll'.  This is strange because when I hit 'w' after ctypes python shows that method in the popup box.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? It works fine in 2.7.12. Note, it will only work on Windows.

Answer (score 31):

As of [`Pillow v9.2.0`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/CHANGES.rst#920-2022-07-01), [`.getsize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getsize) is deprecated, and will be removed in `Pillow v10` on 2023-07-01. Instead, use [`getbbox`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getbbox) or [`getlength`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getlength).

**Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pillow v9.4.0`**

```py
from PIL import ImageFont
font = ImageFont.truetype('times.ttf', 12)

left, top, right, bottom = font.getbbox('Hello world')
width = font.getlength('Hello world')

print(f'left: {left}, top: {top}, right: {right}, bottom: {bottom}, width: {width}')
[out]:
left: 0, top: 2, right: 58, bottom: 11, width: 57.0
```

---

Based on comment from @Selcuk, I found an answer as:

```
from PIL import ImageFont
font = ImageFont.truetype('times.ttf', 12)
size = font.getsize('Hello world')
print(size)
```

which prints (x, y) size as:

> (58, 11)

Here it is as a function:

```
from PIL import ImageFont

def get_pil_text_size(text, font_size, font_name):
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font_name, font_size)
    size = font.getsize(text)
    return size

get_pil_text_size('Hello world', 12, 'times.ttf')
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional to already provided answers: If you have a text containing multiple lines (e.g. 'First line\r\nSecond line') - there might be several ways to get resulting width & height of the text.

"Manual way" would be to split text by lines and get lines maximal width with summary of lines height:

```
from PIL import ImageFont
multiline_string = 'Quick test of multiline text\r\nNew line\nAnother new line here'
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 8)
bboxes = [font.getbbox(k) for k in multiline_string.splitlines()]
width = max([(b[2]-b[0]) for b in bboxes])
height = sum([(b[3]) for b in bboxes])
print('width=' + str(width) + ', height=' + str(height))
```

Another way would be to use the ImageDraw.multiline_textbbox() function:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
multiline_test = 'Quick test of multiline text\r\nNew line\nAnother new line here'
img = Image.new("RGB", (1000, 1000), (255, 255, 255)) # create an image filled with white color
curr_font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 8) # get a font "Arial" with size = 8
curr_context = ImageDraw.Draw(img) # get drawing context of the image
result_box = curr_context.multiline_textbbox((0,0), multiline_test, font=curr_font, font_size=8) # get resulting boundry-box for multiline text with curr_font and font-size = 8
print(result_box) # print the result-box (the width and height could be retrieved there)
# Useful to see the result text:
# curr_context.multiline_text((0, 0), multiline_test, font=curr_font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
# img.show()
```