# Add SVG text within HTML text and make them look identical

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, svg

I'd like text content from a HTML page (actually, a sentence) and text content within a SVG file and make them visually identical and assemble them perfectly: same font, size, alignment and so on.

Like:

```
<p>
    This HTML content. <svg><text>And this is SVG text</text></svg>. Both look identical!
</p>
```

The thing is that I'll never know in advance what will be the size of the SVG text.

I work with Python (I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771863/how-to-calculate-length-of-string-in-pixels-for-specific-font-and-size) you could tackle the viewbox issue thanks to Pillow) but some JS trick should be more adapted I think.

Is there a way to play with the SVG file parameters or CSS to achieve a near perfect visual match between the vector and html texts?

Thank you.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: here you go. Edited my question. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

No.  You will need to know the length of text in advance.  Or calculate it with Javascript (assuming you are running in a browser).