# Python kivy size binding doesn't work on python code

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to put "layout3" inside "layout2" and put "layout2" inside "layout1", so a group of 3 layouts in total. And I'm trying to set their size relative to the "texture_size" inside "layout3" but got a bug. I solved the relative size in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70988737/python-kivy-any-way-to-stretch-a-layout-according-to-its-content-wrapped-text-wh?noredirect=1#comment125498024_70988737) but it's "layout2" inside "layout1" only.

Here is the issue:

[image]

When it's supposed to be like this:

[image]

It's kind of hard to express my idea, but the idea is to create a history chatbox like Messenger and here is how I do it.

(More details: I created "BoxLayout2" with 70% screen to set text's width limit, so when the text expanse longer than that line, it will down the line.

More details for "BoxLayout3": Basically if I use halign="right", the wrapped text will start from the right when down the line. So I need it to halign="left, that why I need "BoxLayout3" to keep the text-align right while it still can start from the left when down the line.)

[image]

.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Chat_history_update(BoxLayout): #<< LAYOUT1
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.app = App.get_running_app()
    def Chat_history_generate(self):
        self.ids['label'] = Wrapped_Label(text="hello"*50,halign="left",valign="top",size_hint=(1,None))
        self.ids['box'] = Wrapped_BoxLayout(pos_hint={"right":1},size_hint=(None,None))   
        self.ids['box_limit'] = Wrapped_BoxLayout_limit(pos_hint={"right":1},size_hint=(.7,None)) 
        self.ids['box_limit'].add_widget(self.ids['box'])
        self.ids['box'].add_widget(self.ids['label'])
        self.add_widget(self.ids['box_limit'])
        
class Wrapped_Label(Button): #<< WRAPPED TEXT WILL BE ADD WIDGET IN LAYOUT3
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.app = App.get_running_app()
        self.bind(
            width=lambda *x: self.setter('text_size')(self, (self.app.root.ids.box_limit.width,None)),
            texture_size=lambda *x: self.setter('size')(self, (self.texture_size[0],self.texture_size[1])))

class Wrapped_BoxLayout(BoxLayout): #<< LAYOUT3
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.app = App.get_running_app()
        self.bind(
            size=lambda *x: self.setter('size')(self, (self.app.root.ids.label.size)))

class Wrapped_BoxLayout_limit(BoxLayout): #<< LAYOUT2
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.app = App.get_running_app()
        self.bind(
            height=lambda *x: self.setter('height')(None,self.app.root.ids.label.height))

     
class Test(App):
    pass

Test().run()
```

.kv file

```
Chat_history_update:
<Chat_history_update>:
    id: update
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint:1,1
    Button:
        text: "generate"
        size_hint: None,None
        size: "100dp","100dp"
        pos_hint: {"top":1}
        on_press: root.Chat_history_generate()
```

Edit: Well... since nothing works, I will have to consider my idea again. Also, if you are looking for more examples you can refer to [this](https://github.com/Kulothungan16/Example-Kivy-Apps/tree/main/Purp-Chat_App_UI). If you have any answer to this question, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Guys, I have managed to find a way. I will upload the solution as soon as I can. But if you have any idea, it's my pleasure.

Comment: This is more challenging than I thought, my solution is to create a FloatLayout between "Layout2" and "Layout3" to use "size_hint_max_x" but still can't make it work correctly.