# PySimpleGUI: How to detect overflow of elements beyond the window limits?

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

In the example below, there is a row with more elements than fit the window.  How can I detect the overflow?

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text(f"word{i}") for i in range(30)]]
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout, size=(500, 100))
window.finalize()

while True:
  event, values = window.read()
  if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
    break
```

Comment: You could set a monspaced font such as Consolas, and count the letters. But much better than that, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771863/how-to-calculate-length-of-string-in-pixels-for-specific-font-and-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of Text element will be different for different font and different-length text.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

font = ("Courier New", 10)
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [[sg.Text(f"word{i}", key=f"TEXT {i}") for i in (0, 10)]]
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout, size=(500, 100), finalize=True)
window.refresh()
text0 = window['TEXT 0'].widget
w0, h0 = text0.winfo_width(), text0.winfo_height()
text10 = window['TEXT 10'].widget
w10, h10 = text10.winfo_width(), text10.winfo_height()
print(w0, h0, w10, h10)

while True:
  event, values = window.read()
  if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
    break

window.close()
```

```py
44 20 52 20
```

Monospace font `('Courier New', 10)` used here, and we can get the basic widths/heights for 4-char and 5-char Texts by above code, they are 44/20 and 52/20.

There are 10 4-char Texts and 20 5-char Texts in your code, also default padding (5, 3) and window default margins (10, 5).

If nothing wrong, you can calculate it as following:

- width = 10 x (44 + 5 x 2) + 20 x (52 + 5 x 2) = 540 + 1240 = 1780 >> 480 = 500 - 10 x 2
- height = 20 << 90 = 100 - 5 x 2

Comment: Yes, I tried a similar approach but the trouble is that `winfo_width()` returns 1 for all words that are beyond the screen boundaries (Tkinter on Ubuntu, 22.04). And for words that are truncated at the screen boundary it returns only the pixel width of the visible part.  Similarly, `winfo_rootx()` is incorrect for words that are outside the screen boundaries.

Comment: IMO, there's no size for invisible element/widget, so you need to calculate what size occupied if all elements visible.

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler solution that would also work with variable pitch fonts, but for now this is perhaps the best we can do.  Tkinter internally must have the relevant information, perhaps I'll find a way to extract it.

Comment: Oops, it's unfortunately not so simple.  If I calculate the width of a single character, I get different results depending of how many characters the string is long.  Apparently Tkinter includes some extra padding, even when `pad=0`.  Demonstration:
`Window("test", [[Text("mmmm", pad=0)], [Text("m", pad=0), Text("m", pad=0), Text("m", pad=0), Text("m", pad=0)]], font="Courier 22", finalize=True)`  I think the mystery padding is 4px at the end of the text, but I can't be sure that it's always this number regardless of OS and font etc.